# How to change Default Object Color in Source Code?

Tags: source-code

All new primitives have their default object.color set to white. Anyone know where to edit the source code so I can change the default object color to gray for example `(.5, .5, .5)` ?

Making a build is no problem, I'm just out of my league navigating the source code (I'm a python newbie).

**This is the property you normally change inside of blender:**

[image]

Comment: I believe you want "\blender-2.92.0\source\blender\makesdna\DNA_object_defaults.h"
but i have not verified
#define _DNA_DEFAULT_Object \
  { \
    /* Type is not very meaningful as a default, normally changed. */ \
    .type = OB_EMPTY, \
    .color = {1, 1, 1, 1}, \

Comment: Works great, thanks a lot! If you post it as an answer I will happily up-vote it :)