# Default color for objects is too white. How do i change that?

Tags: color

Edit > Preferences > Themes > 3D Viewports> Face
I change color to grey but still the default color is white.

how can I change that?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

An Object's color as shown in Viewport Solid shading can be set in Object Properties > Viewport Display.  However, the default color of newly Added objects can't be set in Preferences, [details here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/220234/how-to-change-default-object-color-in-source-code#comment371867_220234).  (Thanks to [nezumi.blend's quick reply at Blender Artists](https://blenderartists.org/t/objects-default-color-preferences-settings-in-3-x/1379732).)

That having been said, there are other settings that might achieve your goal.  An Object's color as shown in Viewport Solid Shading will also be affected by the Viewport Shading's Lighting.  In the below examples, three different gray Matcaps have been used:

[image]

[image]

[image]

If one of these resolves your issue, you can make this the default (without changing anything else) by opening Blender, going directly to the Viewport Solid Shading options, selecting your preferred Matcap, then File > Default > Save Startup File .

Last but not least, in your example pic you're using Material Preview, not Solid:

[image]

Your Viewport Shading should be Solid when Adding new objects, since they're added with no Material and default to bright white.